# Geckodriver for Solaris OS

Tags: python, selenium, solaris, selenium-firefoxdriver

We are using selenium python to automate web application. To launch firefox browser, we need to download geckodriver and place it in /usr/bin. but, we found that linux version geckodriver is not compatible with Solaris os. whenever I am running selenium python to run code on solaris v5.11 , we got an error like "Bad System call(core dumped)"

solaris 11.4
python 2.7.14
selenium 3.141.0
geckodriver 0.24.0

please help to resolve the issue

Comment: *we need to download geckodriver and place it in `/usr/bin`*  Does it **really** require you to place the code in `/usr/bin`?  If so, I'd run far, far away from any bit of code that **requires** you place it in `/usr/bin`.  The proper words to describe such a product can't be used on a family-friendly forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris & Linux use very different system calls, and binaries must be compiled specifically for each one - you cannot copy them across from one system to the other - so you will need to either compile geckodriver yourself or find a version already compiled for Solaris, not Linux.